# Generating excel documents programmatically

Tags: java, excel

Has anyone used a Java based library for generating excel documents? Preferably support for 2003?

Comment: What do you mean by 'documents'? Something that looks like a report or just a spreadsheet full of numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm currently working with Apache POI, ( http://poi.apache.org/index.html ) which is very comprehensive. The 2003 file format version is still in beta, but seems to work well enough. I'm not exercising it's power very much, just straightforward reads and writes of Excel, but it seems reliable.

Comment: Apache seems to offer a library for everything. POI seems to offer exactly what we are looking for. Thanks alot!

Comment: Although, as I stated below, we are generating CSV files already. Can POI import those and generate an excel file. The users of the app are already generating hundreds of files daily, importing each one is becoming a huge waste of time.

Comment: You don't need anything fancy to import CSV in Java. Just look for a good CSV parser such as CSVReader http://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/browse/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.java?spec=svn19&r=19

Comment: @predhme There is already a really good reliable app that imports CSV and writes Excel files. It's called Excel.

Comment: Apache POI library is great, however it is low-level and and it is rarely reasonable to use 'pure' Apache POI for report generation. In order to simplify the process of document creation I would recommend reporting frameworks built on top of Apache POI, like [Jxls](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/) or [Xylophone](https://github.com/CourseOrchestra/xylophone).

Answer (score 6):

Whenever I have to do this I ask myself if one big html table would be enough.

much of the time it is. You can simply write html tags and label it as a .xls file. Excel will open it correctly

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need fancy headings then just output **CSV**.

Comment: The application already generates CSV files. Several users generate hundreds of files a day that they later generate reports. One file to import into excel is fine, but hundreds daily becomes an unnessary time consuming step. Rather, they want that part taken care of... I.e generating the excel file for them.

Comment: Although, since we are already generating the CSV of data, can the "import" process be programmatically done through java?

Comment: How exactly are you importing hundreds of files into Excel? Do they appears on different sheets? are they aggregated together? Are you currently using VBA to do this?

Comment: Well no. The system generates the CSV files. The user then downloads all the CSV's and then opens each one by one with excel. Each time they are presented with a series of dialogs to get the file opened. I want to give the user the option of instead of generating CSV's to generate an EXCEL file.

Answer (score 1):

## [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

I've used it personally for a report that is currently in production.  It's a fairly decent library with sufficient docs, and it's open source.

It works very well, but has a few gotchas you should be aware of.  None of them are deal breakers, just dictate how a few things should be done.  Just be sure to read the [FAQ](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/).  It will explain them and tell you how to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

A formatted HTML table will import correctly, but it would be better to use the Excel XML format from the [Excel 2003 XML Toolbox](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e315c516-2c2c-4870-a189-d47a5d7ffeb3) for more advanced needs (multiple worksheets, formulas, etc).

Comment: Just as a sidenote formulas within a simple HTML table saved as .xls work fine. Whenever something more complex is needed it possible to devise a "template" workbook in Excel, save as XML, then rename that XML into .xls (Excel handles the file just fine), then use the XML file as a template inserting missing info.

http://poi.apache.org/ also works fine.

Comment: As mentioned to another answer, the user is generating hundreds of reports daily and to import each one into excel is a huge waste of time. Need to generate the file directly for the user.

Comment: When I say report, i mean CSV, PDFs, etc. The requirement is to instead of the user having to import the CSV into excel, have the excel file already made for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try SmartXLS for java,
it have more functions than poi and jexcelapi,and it is a commercial product.

http://www.smartxls.com/indexj.htm

Answer (score 1):

I do it with [Jacob](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project) as a general java and [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) solution. However in my reading Jacob does not handle pretty well multiple calls (say millions of calls) and I needed to patch it a bit. These patches were not accepted by Jacob maintainer.

Anyway Jacob is open source (LGPL) and after patching it I have a production environment running for years yet.

After connecting to Excel with COM, you use standard Excel api to process documents. First you try how it works with VBS ([VBScript Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)), then implement in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an excel file with a VBS and then cal the script from java like this:

```
String script = "your_VBS_Name.vbs"
String cmd = "D:\\YourPath" + script;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

to create the script is really simple

open notepad and follow the next example:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs("D:\yourExcel.xls")

objExcel.Quit
```

and then save it as your_VBS_Name.vbs

Thats it!