# Developing Excel reports using Java

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, report, reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating excel documents programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074630/generating-excel-documents-programmatically)

I want to generate excel reports using Java/J2EE. Can anyone let mw know which is the best open source API to do this, which is simple & easy to use.

If anyone can provide me the link to sample programs will be great.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google

Comment: -1: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: I'd suggest something like [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) - lots of options, excel isn't the only output option here or something like [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) if you want to produce the reports by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the Apache POI. They have examples on their [web page](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html). See their website [here](http://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: I am doing research with Jxl to see if it works out... Menawhile wanted to know if anyone has other good thing in mind. Just did not mention that